# Как правильно обращаться к элементам через связи многие-ко-многим?

Tags: база-данных, laravel, связи, многие-ко-многим

Есть такая структура данных, в которой условно есть три таблицы со следующими связями:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моделях прописываю такие связи:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /*
      * Связь Модели Пользователей(Users) с Группами (Group_users)
      * users - group_users
        многие-ко-многим
   */
    public function ingroup() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group_user::class, 'group_works');
    }

  
    /*
    * Связь модели Юзеры (users) с моделью Группы пользователей (Group_works)
        один-ко-многим
    */
    public function peoples() {
        return $this->hasMany(Group_works::class);
    }
}
```

И еще:

```
class Group_user extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name_group',
        'user_id',
    ];

    /*
     * Связь Модели Группы (Group_user) с Модели Юзеры (User)
     многие-к-одному
    */
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    /*
    * Связь модели Группы (Group_user) с Моделью Юзеры (User) - участники группы
      многие-ко-многим
    */
    public function ingroup() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_works');
    }

    /*
   * Связь модели Группы (Group_users) с моделью Группы пользователей (Group_works)
     один-ко-многим
   */
    public function peoples() {
        return $this->hasMany(Group_works::class);
    }

}
```

После чего в контроллере делаю такую функцию:

```
 // форма редактирования группы
    public function edit(Group_user $group, Request $request) {
        $editor = Auth::user()->id;
        $users = User::query()->get();
        return view('admin.groups.edit', compact('editor', 'group', 'users'));
    }
```

А в блейде admin.group.edit пишу такой вызов:

```
Имя группы: {{ $group->name_group }}
Создатель группы: {{ $group->user->name }}

@foreach($users as $user)
  Код юзера: {{$user->id}}
  Имя юзера: {{$user->name}}
  <?php if ($user->ingroup->id == $group->id) {?> Пользователь в группе <?}?>
 @endforeach
```

В результате выдает ошибку:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Как правильно проверить принадлежность пользователя к группе, используя представленные связи?

Comment: Есть тут спецы на ларавел, которые разбираются в этом?

Comment: Многие ко многим через промежуточную таблицу обычно реализуется.. Это окончательная структура базы данных?! Или можно сделать иначе?

Comment: @YauhenKib, тут и есть связь многие-ко-многим через промежуточную таблицу Group_works. Структура должна быть такой, то есть владелец группы, id которой берется из таблицы Users, а есть участники групп, которые хранятся в таблице Group_works и их id также хранятся в таблице Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе реализация многие-ко-многим решается в блейде ларавел следующим образом:

```
Name group: {{ $group->name_group }}
Creator group: {{ $group->user->name }}

@foreach($users as $user)
  Code User: {{$user->id}}
  Name User: {{$user->name}}
  <?php if ($user->ingroup->contains('id', $group->id)) {?> User in a Group <?}?>
@endforeach
```

Ключевая строка `$user->ingroup->contains('id', $group->id)`, так как это коллекция, то работаем с ней именно так. Об этом написано в [англоязычной документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains). В русской документация урезана, и таких подробных описаний нет.